# Android Toolbar: children not matching parent height

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I'm trying to create something like the date selector from the new Google Calendar app. The first part of that is to create a button in the `Toolbar` that fills the parent height and spans the available width. I tried to do that with the following layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    style="@style/DefaultToolbarStyle">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="2014 Events"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Normally, telling a child view (in this case the `LinearLayout`) to match the parent height would make it do just that. However, the `LinearLayout` only expands vertically just enough to fit its child `TextView`.

How can I make children of a `Toolbar` match the `Toolbar`'s height?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"` and `android:layout_height="?`attr/actionBarSize" will give the `Toolbar` a height, that is limited and will layout children within this height.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    style="@style/DefaultToolbarStyle">
   <!--- children views --->

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: That did it! I forgot that the parent had to have a defined height in order for match_parent to work properly.